# Logging in to putty by sesu as superuser and running commands

Tags: unix, batch-file

I need to automate using a bat file where I need the following things to be done:

1. log in to server using putty/plink
2. sesu to super user
3. run certain commands
4. get the outpout in a text file

I can log in to server using:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\putty.exe  username@host -pw password
```

Can someone plesae help me from here?

Answer (score 0):

While my answer will not help you specifically, mainly because I'm looking for part of the answer you are, I can tell you that `plink.exe username@host -pw password < command.txt` will work on everything but the `sesu` part.

Add your commands to a file called `command.txt`.

I used this loop to make it work with multiple hosts

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (hostnames.txt) do call :Foo %%a
goto End

:Foo
set HostName=%1
set UserName=<user>
set PassWord=<pass>
echo y | plink.exe %UserName%@%HostName% -pw %Password% < plink.commands
goto :eof

:End
```